# Can I execute a Unix shell script from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shell, unix

I have written a Unix Shell script which gives the file path and total lines in each file as output.

The script is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

REPO_NAME="abc/def"

     git checkout $REPO_NAME

    git ls-files | grep '\.java$' | xargs wc -l | awk ' BEGIN {printf( "%5s\n", "Count \t Path")} { printf ("%6s\n", $1 "\t" $2 )}' >new.xls
```

I need to call this script from excel through macro and upon executing output is expected to be stored in a new sheet of the same excel where I call this macro.

I have done quite a few research on how to call the script from macro, but failed to find a solution. Please help.

```
Sub run_script()

    Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /K" & "dir /s /b directoryPath", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Comment: Windows cmd (command line) cannot run bash scripts. • Also you would need to tell what is wrong with your code and where you got errors. As well you need to ask a question (you didn't ask one yet) also see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: I need help in writing the vba that call unix script. So my question is " How to call the unix shell script through VBA? "

Comment: You need to call bash to run a bash script. You cannot run a bash script in cmd. Make sure you have bash installed on your windows, find the folder to your bash and start that with `Call Shell` instead of cmd.